# Haskell bit to bool error

Tags: haskell, lava

I'm writing a function which converts a bit to a bool in Kansas Lava.
I can do this in two ways but neither of them works.

The function must do the following:

- Receive a bit (low or high)
- Convert it to its corresponding boolean => False if it's low and True of it's high

First method:

```
bitToBool :: Signal i Bool -> Bool
bitToBool x
  | x==low = False
  | otherwise = True
```

In this method I get the error "Exception: undefined: Eq over a signal"

Second method:

```
bitToBool :: Signal i Bool -> Bool
bitToBool low = False
bitToBool high = True
```

This method always returns False even if the input is high.
This should work because in an another piece of code I do the reverse of this, which works.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for the help

Daan

Comment: What is the definition of `Signal`?

Comment: Don't know Lava, but I assume that you have a problem with uppercase/lowercase. `low` is just a variable in Haskell - it's the same as if you would have used `x` or `_`. Perhaps you meant `Low` and `High`?

Comment: The function in which it works fine:
    boolToBit :: Bool -> Signal i Bool
    boolToBit False = low
    boolToBit True = high

So I don't think its Low and High.

In Kansas Lava Signal is roughly the same as Bit in York Lava but with other features.

Comment: @Daan Mouha If this is regular Haskell, your function `bitToBool` is exactly the same as `bitToBool _ = False` (or `bitToBool = const False`, if you prefer). If you can enable ghc compiler warnings in Lava, it will give you warnings about overlapping pattern matches (because the 2nd line is unreachable) and unused definitions.

Comment: You can't turn a Signal into a Bool in any sensible way.  Signals vary over "time", so comparing it with a static boolean makes little sense.  That's why there's no comparison function for bits.  So, you're on the wrong track here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Answers…

> In this method I get the error "Exception: undefined: Eq over a signal"

That's because the `Eq` instance for `Signal c a` is as such:

```
instance (Rep a, Eq a) => Eq (Signal c a) where
    -- Silly question; never True; can be False.
    (Signal _ _) == (Signal _ _) = error "undefined: Eq over a Signal"
```

You can't compare any two signals.

> What am I doing wrong here?

That's not `low` or `high` from [`Utils`](https://github.com/ku-fpg/kansas-lava/blob/master/Language/KansasLava/Utils.hs), but instead pattern matching. And since the first pattern always matches, you always return `False`.

### …breadcrumbs…

Disclaimer: I've never used Kansas-Lava, I have no idea about hardware programming, and I'm pretty much a Haskell beginner. Now that I've lost all my credibility, lets start on a journey to get that `Bool`!

In order to get something out of a `Signal`, we need to know [what a `Signal` is](https://github.com/ku-fpg/kansas-lava/blob/master/Language/KansasLava/Signal.hs#L36):

```
data Signal (c :: *) a = Signal (S.Stream (X a)) (D a)
```

Great, we can actually pattern match on `Signal`:

```
bitToBool (Signal _ d) = ...
```

Now what can we do with `d`? `d` has type `D Bool` in our case. Lets have a look at the definition of [`low`, `high`](https://github.com/ku-fpg/kansas-lava/blob/master/Language/KansasLava/Utils.hs#L38), and also the helper [`pureS`](https://github.com/ku-fpg/kansas-lava/blob/master/Language/KansasLava/Signal.hs#L59) to get some inspiration:

```
pureS :: (Rep a) => a -> Signal i a
pureS a = Signal (pure (pureX a)) (D $ Lit $ toRep $ pureX a)

high :: (sig ~ Signal i) => sig Bool
high = pureS True

low :: (sig ~ Signal i) => sig Bool
low = pureS False
```

Note the [`Rep` class](https://github.com/ku-fpg/kansas-lava/blob/master/Language/KansasLava/Rep/Class.hs#L25), it gets important later. [`D` is a `newtype`](https://github.com/ku-fpg/kansas-lava/blob/master/Language/KansasLava/Types.hs#L342) wrapper for `Driver E`, [`Lit`](https://github.com/ku-fpg/kansas-lava/blob/master/Language/KansasLava/Types.hs#L292) is one of the constructors for the latter. So we can actually pattern match for the things up to `toRep` and are currently at this point:

```
bitToBool (Signal _ d) = case unD d of
                             Lit r -> ...
                             _     -> False
```

[`toRep`](https://github.com/ku-fpg/kansas-lava/blob/master/Language/KansasLava/Rep/Class.hs#L39) has a dual [`fromRep`](https://github.com/ku-fpg/kansas-lava/blob/master/Language/KansasLava/Rep.hs#L48). And [`pureX`](https://github.com/ku-fpg/kansas-lava/blob/master/Language/KansasLava/Rep/Class.hs#L78) has a somewhat dual [`unX`](https://github.com/ku-fpg/kansas-lava/blob/master/Language/KansasLava/Rep/Class.hs#L33), which in this case leads to `Just Bool` or `Nothing`. We can use `fromMaybe` from `Data.Maybe` to finish our little journey through the Kansas Lava code:

```
bitToBool (Signal _ d) = 
    case unD d of
        Lit r -> fromMaybe False . unX . fromRep $ r
        _     -> False
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't install kansas-lava on my system and therefore couldn't test this solution, but unless I've missed something everything should at least type check.

### …and sad reality

Now that we've seen that it *might* be possible to transform a `Signal i Bool` back to a `Bool`, it isn't wise. It might type check, but so does `unsafePerformIO`.

In the end, you're removing a boolean value from its `Signal` context. However, since this is hardware/VHDL at the end, that's not really sensible:

> You can't turn a Signal into a Bool in any sensible way. Signals vary over "time", so comparing it with a static boolean makes little sense. That's why there's no comparison function for bits. So, you're on the wrong track here. –[augustss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23467604/haskell-bit-to-bool-error/23468568?noredirect=1#comment35995071_23467604)

In fact, the `Eq` and `Ord` instances for `Signal` shouldn't exist from my point of view. Also, some of the constructors shouldn't be exported at all, as duplode hints:

> augustuss raises an important issue in the question comments: even if the constructors are exported, are you supposed to access the representation of a signal? [–duplode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23467604/haskell-bit-to-bool-error/23468568?noredirect=1#comment35997102_23468568)

However, it ultimately depends on your motives, as both original questions have been answered. Unfortunately, I cannot answer the new risen question "Does that make sense", that's up to someone else who has more expertise in this field.

Comment: Is there any reason behind using `high :: (sig ~ Signal i) => sig Bool` instead of `high :: Signal i Bool`? They look equivalent to me.

Comment: @chi: They should be equivalent, but then again, *"I'm pretty much a Haskell beginner"* ^^". Maybe the authors thought that this representation is prettier. On the other hand, they created a `Eq` and `Ord` instances for `Signal` which fail on anything but `max` and `min` - just for the sake of `max` and `min`, which is awful imho.

Comment: augustuss raises an important issue in the question comments: even if the constructors are exported, are you supposed to access the representation of a signal?

Comment: @duplode: Probably not. I've talked to someone who knows a little bit about VHDL and hardware programming, and he was on par with augustuss.

Comment: Wait. Why does `Signal` have an `Eq` instance to begin with?

Comment: @Rhymoid: Frankly, I have no idea and believe it's wrong. I guessed that the authors want to use `max` and `min` from `Ord`, which also needs an `Eq` instance, but a quick search in the repository revealed that even the `Ord` instance isn't used at all. It almost seems like it's there so that it can produce a runtime error. Yay.

Comment: @Zeta: maybe it's there to support the `Num` instance, for older GHCs.

Comment: This code works.
Don't import Language.KansasLava only, but also import Language.KansasLava.Signal to. Else there's an error that it doesn't know what Signal is.